# Using javascript to check true/false condition on viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, viewmodel

I am using local storage variable to hold the location of a users current progress. I have ran into a problem whereby if the last section that the user was on has been since deleted I am getting a target invocation must be set error. This is my code:

```
 if (localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'] != null && localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'] != "") {
            var id = localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'];
        }
        else {
            var id = '@Model.CourseSections.First().CourseSectionID';
        }
```

I need to check using javascript that the localStorage course section is still existing in the database so I created the following ViewModel method:

```
public bool CourseSectionLaunchStillExistCheck(int courseSectionID)
    {
        this.TargetCourseSection = courseSectionRepository.Get(cs => cs.CourseSectionID == courseSectionID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (this.TargetCourseSection != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But when I try to use the following javascript:

```
 if (localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'] != null && localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'] != "") {
            var id = localStorage["Course" + '@Model.Course.CourseID'];
            if ('@Model.CourseSectionLaunchStillExistCheck(id)' != true) {
                var id = '@Model.CourseSections.First().CourseSectionID';
            }
        }
        else {
            var id = '@Model.CourseSections.First().CourseSectionID';
        }
```

It is failing to recognise the **id** parameter saying it does not exist in the current context. How can I ensure that the course section exists using javascript before setting the variable?

Could I use a post such as:

```
 var postData = { 'courseSectionID': id };
            $.post('/Course/CourseSectionLaunchStillExistCheck/', postData, function (data) {
            });
```

and then how could i check if the result of this post data would be true or false?

Comment: You can't do that. Razor/C# executes on the server, and javascript executes later on the client.

Comment: Could I post it using javascript? and check the return?

Comment: Yes, you could use ajax to call out to the server. However, since you need this info on the server, would a cookie, accessible from both the client and server, be a better solution?

Comment: I am working against someone elses code and just really need to get a fix for this in interim but going forward cookie would be better solution, just that if i change it now it will require work throughout

Comment: How can I check if result of post is true?

Comment: In your callback function, try `console.log(data)` to see what `data` looks like, and go from there.

Comment: My post doesnt seem to be doing anything